# Can we write case statement without having else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, case

I have this query:

```
select case when id=1 then 'A'
when id=2 then 'B'
end 
from test
```

It is giving me o/p as

> Id
>   A
>   B
>   NULL
>   NULL
>   NULL

I don't want to have `NULL` values in my output, I only want to compare in A and B, is it possible in case statement.

Comment: Test table has 5 rows: one with id=1, one with id=2 and the others with different value.  If you don't put any WHERE condition,  the resultset will always consist of 5 rows. So,  if you need to restrict the number of rows you need a WHERE condition.  But that's not related to the CASE clause, as it (by itself) doesn't restrict in any way the resultset.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `case` expression can only manipulate the value of an expression, not remove rows from the result. If you want to omit the `null`s from the result, you'll have to add a `where` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'A'
            WHEN id = 2 THEN 'B'
       END 
FROM   test
WHERE  id IN (1, 2) -- HERE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `WHERE` clause to restrict the output.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 'A'
WHEN id=2 THEN 'B'
END 
FROM test
WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

Or if you wanted to showcase some other value instead of `null` use an `else` part inside the `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 'A'
WHEN id=2 THEN 'B' ELSE 'Invalid'
END 
FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select case when id=1 then 'A'
when id=2 then 'B'
end 
from test
where id is not null
```

Or this:

```
select case when id=1 then 'A'
when id=2 then 'B'
end 
from test
where id <> null
```

Comment: What makes you think id will be null? It's likely not going to be null. ids usually aren't.